# Return an error message whne the user selects an invalid file path

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition. I have a Folder Dialog Browser added in my form and I call it when the user presses a button. The folder path string is stored in a string variable and displayed as text in a text box. (maybe I should use a combo box)

My question is: If the user inputs by hand a non existent path, how do I return an error message, stop the file creation into the invalid path, and return to my main form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Directory.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) method from the `System.IO` namespace:

```
If Directory.Exists(directoryChosenByUser) Then
    ' Proceed
Else
    ' Return
End If
```

Note that, due to various circumstances (e.g. the directory is removed between `Directory.Exists` and your file creation code, or the user does not have permissions to write to that directory, or the directory is on a network drive and the network connection suddenly fails, ...), your file creation might fail nonetheless. Thus, it might still make sense to catch the error (using [`Try ... Catch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx)) and provide a meaningful error message to the user (instead of letting your application "just crash").